# getting strange Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9) crash error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, exc-bad-access, xctestcase

I'm writing unit test for `MyClass`. consider below code:

**MyClass.swift**

```swift
class MyClass {    
    let collectionPeriod: TimeInterval
    var previousCollectDate: Date?

    init(period: TimeInterval, previousCollectDate: Date?) {
        self.collectionPeriod = period
        self.previousCollectDate = previousCollectDate
    }

    func schedule() { }

    func collect() { }
}
```

**MyClassTests.swift**

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import MyModule

class CollectableTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: MyClass!

    override func setUp() { }

    override func tearDown() {
        self.sut = nil
    }

    func testSchedule_NotScheduledBefore_CollectExecutesAfterCollectionPeriod() {
//        let _ = Collectable(period: 11, previousCollectDate: nil)

        self.sut = MockCollectable(suiteName: self.testSuiteName)

        self.sut?.schedule()
    }
}

class MockCollectable: Collectable {

    init(suiteName: String) {
        super.init(period: 5.0, previousCollectDate: Date())
    }    
}
```

the strange thing happens here, when I execute my test in this condition, I get a crash error in
`self.sut = MockCollectable(suiteName: self.testSuiteName)`
but when I add (uncomment) line 
`let _ = Collectable(period: 11, previousCollectDate: nil)`
that literally does nothing but creating one instance that is unused in code, the crash disappears. any idea?

and maybe debug navigator info can be useful:

```
#0  0x00000001d0dd2aec in swift_checkMetadataState ()
#6  0x0000000104858398 in type metadata accessor for CollectableTests.MockCollectable ()
#7  0x00000001048582c8 in CollectableTests.testSchedule_NotScheduledBefore_CollectExecutesAfterCollectionPeriod() 
#51 0x00000001c7a49d0c in UIApplicationMain ()
#52 0x00000001025882b0 in main
```

Comment: it really seems like a bug in Xcode 11.1 or swift 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this happens and I don't know why below solution works for it. if anyone has more information I will be glad to know.

**Solution**
checking `Allow testing Host Application APIs` for test target in Xcode, fixed the error.